# BTA41 600 V, 40 A TRIAC: can it really handle 40 A current in continuous conduction?

Tags: power, current, power-electronics, triac

I was considering using a [BTA41](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/bta41.pdf) 600 V, 40 A TRIAC in my project. The leads of the TRIAC are so small that I have doubts about the amount of current it can handle. Its current rating is 40 A; can it really withstand such high currents?

Comment: See this for "complete" mechanic data, "P" unknown (pin area is about 0.9 mm^2  ... https://www.sunrom.com/download/696.pdf

Comment: See this for long cables https://www.spwales.com/cable-size-current-rating-chart Don't forget that "leads" are very short ... and heat can be removed also with "water" ...

Comment: r is 0.19 mOhm (length=10mm, section=0.9mm^2) -> 40 A -> power = 0.304 W ... under pulse conditions: 100 A -> 1.9 W ... 400 A -> 30.4 W

Answer (score 2):

TOP-3 package seems to be the same as TO-3P, in any case that thing is not "small" anything, that thing is freaking huge, 16mm across and 21 mils high! At least in terms of PCBA components you usually see, anything bigger than that goes into territory of screw/bolt mounted..

The pins are ~1.25mm wide and 0.5mm thick, that's a nice solid chunk of copper right there. Don't worry about those pins, they can do the job, however..

As pointed out, that "40A" presumes you can dissipate the heat safely from the package, which is hardly given. This is something you'll run into over and over, expecially on tiny components like SOT-23 this gets really obnoxious, but I digress.

**It's a bad idea to use components with their max ratings in general so the following is just to give an idea**

Eyeballing figure 2 from the datasheet you have to keep the case at 80-ish degrees for the insulated version and 95-ish for the non-insulated for 40A capacity. If you look left to the figure 1, you'll see that thing dissipates some 47W at 40A current, In other words, you need a heatsink which will not let the temperature rise more than 55C at 47W. Call it 55/45 and you get 1.22C/W requirement. It may not seem much for current GPU/CPU numbers but trust me, that's not a subtle heatsink. Quick check at digi-key gives this thing as the smallest passive heatsink that'd fit the bill.

https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/wakefield-vette/511-3U/5068130

For something **more reasonable**, you need some derating to keep things safe(r). There are no real hard rules about this kind of thing but if you fall back to IPC-9592B, it gives Thyristor/Triac current limit as max 90% and junction temperature as -25C from the datasheet max. Using forced convection (fan) also seems reasonable, otherwise the ambient won't stay at 25C for very long and your temperature margin shrinks together with the air heating around the triac.

**This triac is standard type**, so you have to be very careful with voltage and current slopes as well as how you treat the gate. Do it wrong and the triac may switch on when you want it switched off and/or go "pop". This is a complex topic beyond a single post, but ST Micro has a series of application notes on the topic, e.g. AN437, AN4363 and AN5114, on the datasheet the key charts are figure 7 through 9.